# Android File Logging

Tags: android, logging

I'm planning to implement a logging mechanism for security-related messages in Android. I want to be able to use it in the Android source code like the **Log** class, e.g. `SecuLog.log(String msg);`

It shall in the following ways differ from the normal Log

- No levels like DEBUG, INFO, etc...
- Output should directly go into a **File** on the device. There must not be the need of  redirecting Logcat output for example.

As multiple processes shall be able to log security-related messages I failed with just implementing a LoggingClass in com.android.util with a static PrintWriter.

```
static {
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter("data/secu.log");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception initializing SecuLog.", e);
    }
}
```

This did not work, because Android is designed to run multiple dalvik-VMs that all try to access the given file. So i need some kind of non-blocking File I/O.

Is there a way to reuse any logging mechanism from Android without the need to explicitly redirect logcat output?

How else can I achieve a simple file logging mechanism, that can be called from every other process? Should I implement a logging **Service**? Does this service has to be a bound service or a started service? Do I have to use [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to log, your own application or **all** applications on the device? Should only log messages that you send to `YourLogger.log(...)` be logged to the file or should the logger be able to "catch" log messages from elsewhere?

Comment: I want to log from **all** applications and only messages from MyLogger.log(...) shall be logged.

Comment: From "all" applications as in only applications **that you have written** and added `MyLogger.log(...)` to? Do you want all log messages to go to the same file, or can it be different files?

Comment: I want to be able to `import MyLogger` and use its logging methods in every .java file of the Android source code, like with the normal Log class. The output shall go into one single file.

Comment: That may prove a lot harder than you think; what about having a unique log per application, and a viewing tool which collects and assembles them all, sorting by timestamp?

Comment: Seems like you're right and I have to fall back on file splitting or using the sqlite database to store the log messages.

Comment: Consider using a log framework like [logback-android](http://tony19.github.io/logback-android), which allows you to log to a local file.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas! Though my actual problem persists, I think that I'll fall back on the solution with multiple logging files and a viewing tool which puts everything togheter.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I tried implementing it with `writer = new PrintWriter("data/secu" + android.os.Process.myPid() + ".log");` But it seems to fail every time, the Pid is != 1000, and every time it is 1000 it works. That does not make sense to me. Do you have an idea, where this might come from?

Comment: Ownership of the folder and mode bits only allowing the owner to write there?

Comment: So PID 1000 seems to be the owner. Why is that? Because it opened it first there? Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the comments to my question I chose the following solution:

- created multiple log files
- one file for each process
- used processId as suffix for log files
- designed a log viewing app, that puts all logs togheter

For my logging class I used the following code:

```
static {
    try {
        File file = new File("data/secu" + android.os.Process.myPid() + ".log");
        file.createNewFile();
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        file.setExecutable(true, false);
        writer = new PrintWriter(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception initializing SecuLog.", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old by now. But I recently did this work and want to share it.
Suggestions are welcome.
Multiple libs are available for this purpose, but if you want to do it yourself, here you go.

```
fun log(tag: String?, message: String) {

        try {

            val direct = File("${Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)}/$DIRECTORY_NAME")

            if (!direct.exists()) {
                direct.mkdir()
            }

            val fileNameTimeStamp = "${SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())}"
            val logTimeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss:SSS aaa", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

            val fileName = "$fileNameTimeStamp.html"

            val file = File("${Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)}/$DIRECTORY_NAME" + File.separator + fileName)

            file.createNewFile()

            if (file.exists()) {

                val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file, true)
                //Here I have added a html tag to beautify/highlight the output in file.
                fileOutputStream.write("<p style=\"background:lightgray;\"><strong style=\"background:lightblue;\">&nbsp&nbsp$logTimeStamp :&nbsp&nbsp</strong>&nbsp&nbsp$message</p>".toByteArray())
                fileOutputStream.close()

            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while logging into file : $e")
        }

    }
```

The purpose of keeping it html file is to open it browser and could highlight different items. Becuase log searching and debugging is very boring and beautifying could reduce the mental stress.

Output file looks like:

[image]